# Can't Display Record Field Update Result in MySQL PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After pressing "Update" button, It should update and then to display the result of an updated record record (a single updated record with selected columns). However, the page only displays table column names without any records and a few errors. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<strong><font size="6">Sales Log - Main</font><font size="5"><br />
(Transaction Status Update)</font></strong>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#6E6E6E" text="Azure">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'jack';
$dbpass = 'somepassword';
$myDBname = 'sales';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $myDBname);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$FileNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FileNumber']);
$Status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Status']);

//$sql = "UPDATE saleslog SET Status = '".$Status."' WHERE FileNumber = '".$FileNumber."'"; //this worked fine then code below was introduced

$sql = "UPDATE saleslog 
       SET Status = '$Status'
       WHERE FileNumber = '$FileNumber'" ;

mysql_select_db('realestate');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully!\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<br />
<br />
<td width="100">File Number</td>
<td><input name="FileNumber" type="text" id="FileNumber"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Status</td>
<td><input name="Status" type="text" id="Status" value="Closed"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
<input name="reset" type="reset" onclick="resetForm(''); return false;" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>


$sql="SELECT FileNumber, Address, Status FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>FileNumber</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Address</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Status</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['FileNumber']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['Address']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['Status']; ?></td>

</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: updated the answer. it is a working program. delete the lines marked '/* delete line */

Comment: Added 'rows found' summary line. You do not need to delete any lines, it should just work. I will add details of what the table looks like to ensure we have the same table layout. Remember that all names must match exactly as regards letter case. It is working fine here. It shows the updated row after the update. It should work on PHP versions earlier than 5.3.

Comment: finally found out why "... but it still does not display the last edited record or any record. ". I had the wrong PHP tags when trying to echo the data in the record. Is fixed now. see '<?= ' in the code or click on the 'edited <when>' link at the bottom of the answer to see the changes. 'Better late than never...' sigh. ;-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various errors in the code.

Converted directly to 'mysqli'. I have not changed the logic in any way.

Tested code: PHP 5.3.18. mysql 5.5 window xp.

Added table layout.

No need to delete any lines as i have converted them to comments. Just copy and paste.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
<strong><font size="6">Sales Log - Main</font><font size="5"><br />
(Transaction Status Update)</font></strong>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#6E6E6E" text="Azure">
<?php
    // always connect to the database...
    $mysqlhost   = 'localhost';
    $mysqluser   = 'jack';
    $mysqlpass   = 'test';
    $myDBname    = 'sales'; // should this be 'realestate'


    // why select a different database then when you connected? was 'sales'
    //  mysql_select_db('realestate'); /* why? */

    $mysqli = new mysqli($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpass, $myDBname);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // set the database table to use...
    $tbl_name = "`saleslog`";


    if (isset($_POST['update'])) // we have some record to change...
    {
        // do not need to escape input as we will use prepared query and bind variables
        $FileNumber = $_POST['FileNumber'];
        $Status     = $_POST['Status'];

        //$sql = "UPDATE saleslog SET Status = '".$Status."' WHERE FileNumber = '".$FileNumber."'"; //this worked fine then code below was introduced

        $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name
                SET `Status` = ?
                WHERE `FileNumber` = ?" ;

        $updateQuery =  $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        if ($updateQuery === false) { // drat
            die('updateQuery: '. $mysqli->error);
        }

        // bind the variables to the query
        $updateQuery->bind_param('si', $Status, $FileNumber);

        $allOk = $updateQuery->execute();
        if (!$allOk) { // drat
            die('updateQuery: '. $updateQuery->error);
        }

        if ($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {
            echo "Updated data successfully!<br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "FileNumber: $FileNumber was not changed<br />";
        }
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
      <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tr><br /><br />
          <td width="100">File Number</td><td>
            <input name="FileNumber" type="text" id="FileNumber"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">Status</td><td>
            <input name="Status" type="text" id="Status" value="Closed"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"> </td><td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"> </td><td>
            <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
            <input name="reset" type="reset" onclick="resetForm(''); return false;" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
<?php

}

// always use 'prepare'
if (!empty($FileNumber)) {
    $whereClause = " WHERE `FileNumber` = ?";
}
else {
    $whereClause = " ORDER BY `FileNumber`";
}

$sql = "SELECT `FileNumber`, `Address`, `Status`
       FROM $tbl_name
       $whereClause";

$selectQuery = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if (!empty($FileNumber)) {
    $selectQuery->bind_param('i', $FileNumber);
    $originalFileNumber = $FileNumber;
}

$allOk = $selectQuery->execute();
if (!$allOk) { // drat
    die('selectQuery: '. $selectQuery->error);
}

// results will be placed in these three variables when we fetch the row later
$selectQuery->bind_result($FileNumber, $Address, $Status);

?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center"><strong>FileNumber</strong></td>
            <td align="center"><strong>Address</strong></td>
            <td align="center"><strong>Status</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <?php $rowCount = 0; ?>
        <?php while($selectQuery->fetch()):  // the data will be in the 'bind_result' variables ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= $FileNumber ?></td>
            <td><?= $Address; ?></td>
            <td><?= $Status; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php $rowCount++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<td>
    <?php if ($rowCount >= 1): ?>
      <strong><?php echo $rowCount; echo $rowCount == 1 ? ' row found' : ' rows found'; ?></strong>
    <?php elseif (!empty($originalFileNumber)): ?>
      <strong>No rows found for FileNumber: <?php echo $originalFileNumber; ?></strong>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong>No rows found in the table!!!></strong>
    <?php endif ?>
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$mysqli->close(); // free the database connection -- not needed but harmless
?>
```

Table data:

```
FileNumber  Status  Address        
----------  ------  ---------------
         1  open    here at home!  
         2  Closed  what ever
```

Table layout:

```
*DDL Information*/
-------------------

CREATE TABLE `saleslog` (
  `FileNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Address` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FileNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: with the number of frameworks and pdo available for PHP i do not see why people are still trying to reinvent the wheel. Just use one of them and this will heal most of this common DB mistakes.

Comment: @StephanePaquet, i agree, even some of the simple database abstraction libraries would be better and safer than this. Still, they need answers ;-/

Comment: Hmm... I have added as you suggested, but I am getting errors "undefined veriable $tbl_name" and "undefined veriable $lastId"

Comment: Ryan, thank you so much. All errors are gone, and it updates the "FileNumber" field in the table, but it still does not display neither the last edited record.

Comment: I mean it updates the "FileNumber" field in the table, but it still does not display the last edited record or any record. Once I press "Update" button, it displays confirmation "Updated data successfully!" with the empty table, but lists selected columns names (FileNumber  Address  Status) and above column names it says "List data from mysql"

Comment: I am quiet new to MySQL and PHP that's why I use funky outdated codes. I do feel embarrassed for my involuntary "stupidity".

Comment: Ignorance can be changed. I suggest a look at a tutorial such as: ['MySQLi' for Beginners](http://codular.com/php-mysqli). See the section on 'prepared statements' to understand the code provided.

Comment: Thank you for the article! I am reading it right now. Quiet interesting and plain (I needed plain). Regarding last code, once I click "Update" button, it still displays following with no last record displayed, just column names (I begin to think that this might be an issue with my PHP or MySQL settings, if not Apache) Anyway, I will mark it as answered, since it is working for you: Sales Log - Main
(Transaction Status Update) Updated data successfully!
List data from mysql
FileNumber  Address  Status
  
1 row found

Comment: if you update you question with the version of PHP that you are using then i will investigate. just put **phpinfo();** in your script and when run it will tell you the PHP version right at the top. :-) Also, glad you are enjoying the tutorial.